# OpenShift Pro: Binary Deployment With Changed Version Of Tomcat Configuration

Tags: tomcat, deployment, configuration, binary, openshift

I am in the final phase of my migration from **OpenShift v2** to **OpenShift Pro**.

For the **LIVE** version I export a war to a 'deployments' folder and do a **binary deployment** to **OpenShift Pro** like this:

```
oc new-build --image-stream=jboss-webserver30-tomcat8-openshift --binary=true --name=live

oc start-build live --from-dir=/Users/lyndon/git/mmjlive/deployments
```

My question is:-

**How do I deploy an altered server.xml file to Tomcat when doing a binary deployment?**

**Please Note**. I can do it with a 'normal' **source deployment** via a git push, this was the subject of an earlier question that has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is VERY simple...

Create a structure like so:

```
/project
  /configuration
    server.xml
  /deployments
    ROOT.war
```

And run the command:

```
oc start-build live --from-dir=/Users/lyndon/project --follow=true --wait=true
```

And voila!

In the output from above, as if by magic:-

```
Copying config files from project...
'/home/jboss/source/configuration/server.xml' -> '/opt/webserver/conf/server.xml'
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you are using servlet/JSP container.
If so, to override any context elements, introduce a `context.xml` in the application. Add the context parameters with `override="true"`.

```
<Context ...>
  ...
  <Parameter name="sereverContextParamName" value="newOverridenValue"
         override="true"/>
  ...
</Context>
```

A complete documentation for version 5.5 is [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html)

If you just need to add few context parameters for runtime, simply change your web.xml to include `<context-param>` elements.

### EDIT 1:

Based on discussion in the comment, it seems that the OP need to override `server.xml` to add `docbase`; which a deploy time config.

In the war configuration the docBase can be configured in `META-INF/context.xml` within the codebase, which is referred by tomcat for setting config.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Context docBase="yourDocBase"></Context>
```

The other solution, which worked for the OP is given by OP itself, which is more in the context of how openshift set a custom server.xml.

Comment: I am using Tomcat 8 on OpenShift Pro. I want to add this line to server.xml: <Context docBase="/opt/app-root/data/documents" path="/documents" />. Not override an existing value. I have done this with a source code deployment via git. Now I have to do it in a binary deployment.

Comment: In case of a war deployment, you cannot specify a `path`; the name of the war file is the path. Are you deploying your war outside of webapp folder?

Comment: gyan, I don't understand your question.  I run oc start-build live --from-dir=/Users/lyndon/git/mmjlive/deployments in a terminal window on my Mac, when the build completes at OpenShift, the deployment runs. I am not doing anything clever or unusual.

Comment: Then, you should not need anything .. any setting at all. Do you see your war (or exploded file for your war) in `/opt/webserver/webapps/`? Default deployment just pushes the file here and you should be able to access the application via `http://<routeurl>/<warNameWithoutExtension>`

Comment: Yes, the app gets deployed and works. I just cannot request documents from /opt/app-root/data/documents because I cannot change server.xml to add that folder as a docBase. I can do it on a source code deployment but NOT on a binary deployment.

Comment: It simply means that the problem is not war deployment or its functionality. You are simply trying to add another path as docBase (which is kind of totally different functionality) to server static files. And you are trying to make tomcat configuration change (not related to war deployment) in the same deployment process. If I get it right, then you are only left with two options - 1) Bundle your documents in the war to serve, tomcat would be happy to serve those as static file 2) make change to server.xml to inform about a docBase

Comment: Number 2 IS exactly what I want to do. Change server.xml. I have done this for a source code deployment and it is very easy. Now I want to do it for a binary deployment. That is the problem...

Comment: Have you tried adding `META-INF/context.xml` in the source code and create a war, then deploy. Please see post update and let me know.

Comment: In context.xml do yo mean it should be like this: <Context docBase="/opt/app-root/data/documents" path="/documents" />

Comment: Nope, no path allowed for context.xml inside a war. It will not change anything. For wars, the path is their name. It is the last option, if it works because tomcat has a define set of rules to set docBase for war. I am thinking if it can honor the docBase from the context.xml of the war to serve static file and also allow you to access your application via name of the war. Never deployed like that earlier, but this is the last option probably.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but I need to be able to serve documents from outside of the Tomcat environment. I will continue to search for a solution...